# Substrate-based PoW Public Blockchains

Tags: blockchain, public

Are there any public Substrate-based running PoW chains out there except [Kulupu](https://github.com/kulupu/kulupu)?
If you know, please share some links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the writing this post, Kulupu is the only public running PoW Substrate chain.